# unknown characters in CC number field with SqPaymentform

Tags: square-connect

Using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>
```

In the CC number field rather than bullets it is the "unknown character" symbol - a gray diamond with a question mark in it. The field is created with

```
<iframe id="sq-card-number" name="sq-card-number" class="sq-input" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="18" src="https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber&amp;app_id=sandbox-sq0idp-TG4xugNydWOz_H_OO4W45Q">
```

The html page starts with

```
<!doctype html>
```

and in the head is

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

though that shouldn't be necessary for html5.

Any suggestions, other than live with it?

Comment: Never seen that before! Could you post a screenshot? And what is your browser/version/device info?

Comment: @ tristansokol  
Don't know how to post a screen shot, but here is a link to one.
[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/igktgu)
Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Page is [link](https://hnrep.com/sq.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the bullets in the value of the placeholder var for the CC number field. The file with the bullets in it had been saved with ANSI encoding rather than UTF-8.